# Unity, shader, vertexID

Tags: unity, shaders, glsl, hlsl, vertex

I'm writing a shader and I just wanna ask if it's possible to get the ID of the vertex that is currently being manipulated. I read something about gl_vertexID, but I couldn't find out if that is something I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Added the vertexIDs in a second uv(set x value to the id) channel in the mesh(from my c# code), and then in the shader I could use the ids as I needed, example:

```
     void function(inout appdata_full v) 
     {     
          int vertexID = v.texcoord1[0]; 
          ...
     }
```

Comment: Will do! Have to wait 20 hours apparently. Thanks for the reminder tho :)

Comment: VertexID is auto-generated as a system variable in Direct3D Shader Model 4.0 (Feature Level 10.0 hardware or later), but for older shader models you have to generate it yourself as was done in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't seem to have much trouble doing this.
Here's a sample vert shader input struct:

```
struct VS_INPUT
{
 float4 pos        : POSITION;
 float3 norm       : NORMAL;
 float2 uv         : TEXCOORD0;
 float4 col        : COLOR0;
 uint   id         : SV_VertexID;
};
```

Good luck!  I hope it helps!